# What dictates the order of data in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

What determines the order of items in a dictionary(specifically in Python, though this may apply to other languages)? For example:

```
>>> spam = {'what':4, 'shibby':'cream', 'party':'rock'}
>>> spam
{'party': 'rock', 'what': 4, 'shibby': 'cream'}
```

If I call on spam again, the items will still be in that same order. But how is this order decided?

Answer (score 1):

According to python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries),

> Dictionaries are sometimes found in other languages as “associative
>   memories” or “associative arrays”. Unlike sequences, which are indexed
>   by a range of numbers, dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be
>   any immutable type; strings and numbers can always be keys.

They are arbitary, again from docs:

> A dictionary’s keys are almost arbitrary values. Values that are not
>   hashable, that is, values containing lists, dictionaries or other
>   mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object
>   identity) may not be used as keys. Numeric types used for keys obey
>   the normal rules for numeric comparison: if two numbers compare equal
>   (such as 1 and 1.0) then they can be used interchangeably to index the
>   same dictionary entry. (Note however, that since computers store
>   floating-point numbers as approximations it is usually unwise to use
>   them as dictionary keys.)

Answer (score 1):

The order in an ordinary dictionary is based on an internal hash value, so you're not supposed to make any assumptions about it.

Use `collections.OrderedDict` for a dictionary whose order you control.

Answer (score 0):

Because dictionary keys are stored in a hash table. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table:

> The entries stored in a hash table can be enumerated efficiently (at constant cost per entry), but only in some pseudo-random order.